# How to filter Cyrillic words in gmail using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, regex, gmail, cyrillic

please help!

My goal is to filter the gmail inbox messages with Google App Script and find the specified Cyrillic word in it.

For example, I have a function that parse the messages:

```
var parseRawContent = function(rawContent)

 {
    var lines = rawContent.split("\n");
    var result = {};
    var headers = {};
    var body = "";

    var currentHeaderKey = null;
    var headerParsed = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].trim() === "") {
            if (headers.date === undefined) {
                continue;
            }

            headerParsed = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (!headerParsed) {
          var headerParts = lines[i].match(/^([-a-z]+):(.*)/i);

            if (headerParts) {
                currentHeaderKey = headerParts[1].toLowerCase();
                headers[currentHeaderKey] = headerParts[2].trim();
            } else {
                // Header continues on new line
                headers[currentHeaderKey] += " " + lines[i].trim();
            }
        } else {
            body += lines[i];
        }
    }

    if (headers["content-transfer-encoding"] === "base64") {
        try {
            body = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(body)).getDataAsString();
        } catch (err) {
            getLogger().log("Could not base64 decode body.")
        }
    }

    result.headers = headers;
    result.body = body;

    return result;
};
```

Also, I have a function to spot the Russian text in the raw messages:

```
function(m, raw) {
    "Has 'привет' in body"
    return raw.body.match(/привет/i)
},
```

All the code above is taken from (https://github.com/spamzero/spamzero/blob/master/spam-zero.js)

Problem: the match does not happen.

What might be an issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

UPD: I found following issues with parsing the Gmail messages/threads

- Russian text can be encoded with "Quoted Printable" encoding;
- Russian text can be encoded with "Base64" encoding;

To manage all above the following changes were made for the original functions.

Parse function:

```
var parseRawContent = function(rawContent) {
    var lines = rawContent.split("\n");
    var result = {};
    var headers = {};
    var body = "";
    var currentHeaderKey = null;
    

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        // Checking that the line is a header (starts with "<something>:")
        var headerParts = lines[i].match(/^([-a-z]+):(.*)/i);
        if (headerParts) {
            currentHeaderKey = headerParts[1].toLowerCase();
            headers[currentHeaderKey] = headerParts[2].trim();
        } else {

            // Decode Quoted-Printable to UTF-8 if applicable
            if (headers["content-transfer-encoding"] === "quoted-printable") {
                // check that the line is started with "=A0" or similar:
                if (lines[i].match(/^=[0-9A-H]{2}=(.*)/)) {  
                    try {
                        lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/=\s$/g, ''); // Replace the last "="
                        lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/={1}/g, '%'); // Replace all the "=" with "%" for decodeURI method
                        lines[i] = lines[i].split(" "); // Split the line into the words divided by space
                            
                        var DecodedLine = ""
                            for (var j = 0; j < lines[i].length; j++) {
                            var SubLines = "";
                            SubLines = decodeURI(lines[i][j]);
                            DecodedLine += SubLines;
                            }
                        lines[i] = DecodedLine;
                    } catch (err) {
                    getLogger().log("Could not quoted-printable decode body.")
                    }
                } else {
                    continue
                }
            }

            // Decode base64 to UTF-8 if applicable
            if (headers["content-transfer-encoding"] === "base64") {
                try {
                lines[i] = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(lines[i])).getDataAsString();
                } catch (err) {
                getLogger().log("Could not base64 decode body.")
                }
            }  
        // Add everything that is not a header incl. decoded lines to BODY        
        body += lines[i];
        }
    }

    result.headers = headers;
    result.body = body;

    return result;
};
```

Spot function:

```
function(m, raw) {
    "Has Russian words 'тест' or 'привет' in body"
    var matchers = [/тест/i, /привет/i
    ]
    for (var i = 0; i < matchers.length; i++) {
        if (raw.body.match(matchers[i])) {
              return true;
        }
    }
},
```

An issue has been closed.

P.S.: I am a noob in coding. Please do not hesitate to comment/suggest more efficient solution.